# Obfuscate Images in EaselJS

Tags: node.js, easeljs, createjs

**Is there any way to protect your sprites on EaselJS?**
Currently is too easy to download the sprites.

On chrome just go to console -> resources [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNYvN.png)

I made a resarch before i made this answer and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973528/canvas-disable-image-download?answertab=active#tab-top) . 
That could be very nice. Also we don't need to save the slices in a json like he said, if we have a [shuffle seed](https://github.com/webcaetano/SeededShuffle).

But, i didn't find any thing in nodejs(back-end) to make this image shuffle.

I tried Node [GM](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) but its looks too complicaded to bind a image on top of another with (w,h,x,y,offsetX,offsetY)

I know always will have a way to "hack" the resource. But at least offer some difficult.

Comment: I did it myself. https://github.com/webcaetano/image-scramble

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple approaches is to encode images to base64, store them as part of Javascript and decode at runtime. See:

[Convert and insert Base64 data to Canvas in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473205/convert-and-insert-base64-data-to-canvas-in-javascript)

But obviously this will increase download size.

Personally, I would not go this route for "normal" applications or games, unless it is really justified or put on me as an external requirement. For example, one can easily extract assets from the android APK, but this does not seem an area of concern for most of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

The user's browser downloads those images whether you want it or not. Otherwise, they wouldn't be able to display them.

At any given time, any user can just right click on any image on the site and click SAVE AS, you can't stop it, and you shouldn't try.

If you don't want people downloading your work, don't put it on the public facing internet.

Comment: **...**
If you right click in a canvas you will get only a screenshot of the stage. 
At least you know what is EaselJS?

Comment: @user2081518 It doesn't matter. The user downloads *the entire sprite* because it's a resource you use. Even since before the user attempted to save it, the user's browser saved it on the hard disk with cache/whatever. If you don't want this to happen, don't use sprites. And if your library doesn't allow that, use a different library. The *entire point* of sprite is that the client downloads the whole thing once and doesn't need to worry about more resources. What you are looking for is an oxymoron to that principle.